# android-aac-enc does not work on Samsung Star phone

Tags: android, m4a

I need to implement a audio recording with pause/resume functionality and the output has to be m4a file format. So I implemented a recording in PCM format. Then I'm using (for the old Android versions only)
the library that I found here - https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc

The strange part is that it is working for a lot of devices (like my nexus 7) but does not work for Samsung Star. There is no crash, the player after that tries to play it but there is only a very strange noise.

I suspect that it is something with the architecture of the processor but don't know what might be and how to fix it.

Please if you have experience with that library help me. (or if you know another better one that I could easily integrate)

Thanks and Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finally I managed to make it working.
So basically in the documentation is written that you could call multiple times encode method. So initially I implemented it by encoding on a small chunks. The problem is that it seems that at the end of each chunk it puts also and an awful beep :-(

So I know it is not a perfect solution but what I manage to make working is to load the whole file in a Byte array and to encode it at once...

If somebody finds better solution please let me know.